# Tracking Play Count over Multiple Months

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page written in PHP that has a playlist of songs. When a user listens to a song I have some javascript run some PHP to update a field in the MySQL database that increments a 'play count' number.

This is good for a running total of how many times a song was listened to, but I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for how to get it so I could easily break down by month or by week the play count of a particular song.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add a table to your database that would track the timestamp, song, and user.  You should still keep the `play count` number in the `users` table for easier querying.  But if you want to break down number of plays by date you'll need the other table.

Something like

```
user_plays
----------
play_id
user_id
song_id
date_played
```

Then you can run a query on that table to get a count of number of plays for a date range.

For a user:

```
SELECT COUNT(play_id) as num_plays
FROM user_plays
WHERE user_id = ? AND date_played BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

For a song:

```
SELECT COUNT(play_id) as num_plays
FROM user_plays
WHERE song_id = ? AND date_played BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: +1, I would go further and add that if your dataset is large (>1 million rows), consider creating "aggregate" tables (e.g. user_plays_agg, user_plays_2012-01...), that already have the counts by day and my month.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I need to implement, and not much more difficult then what I'm already doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store more details than just a total play count. I'd introduce an additional table to record all of the playback events, storing the ID of the track and the timestamp. Then you can query this table for all of the plays relating to a particular track between whatever dates.

Obviously querying a huge table like that is something you'll want to cache.